# React + Redux : Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Body)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to connect my component to a store using the `react` + `redux` + `react-redux` + `react-router` philosophy. I'm getting this error even though the parent is encapsulated with store:

```
[Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Body)". 

Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Body)".]
 name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }
```

### Code (imports shortened for brevity)

#### components/Table.jsx

```
export default class Table extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        {this.props.barcodes.map(barcode =>
          <p key={barcode.value}>
        )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

#### containers/BarcodeListing.jsx

```
import Table from 'components/Table'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { barcodes: state.barcodes };
}

@connect(mapStateToProps)
class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Table barcodes={barcodes}/>
      );
  }
}

export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Container>
        <Body />
      </Container>
      );
  }
}
```

#### routes.jsx

```
import BarcodeListing from 'containers/barcodeListing';

const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, reducers, {
  routing: routeReducer
}));

const finalCreateStore = compose(window.devToolsExtension())(createStore);

  const store = finalCreateStore(reducer, {}); 

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={BrowserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
        <Route path='/' component={BarcodeListing} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

### package.json

```
"react": "shripadk/react-ssr-temp-fix",
"react-dom": "^0.14.6",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
"react-redux": "^4.0.6",
"react-router": "^1.0.0-beta3",
"react-style": "^0.5.5",
"redux": "^3.0.6",
"redux-logger": "^2.3.2",
"redux-simple-router": "^1.0.2",
```

Comment: Did you install `react-router-redux` or `react-router`?

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko Yes, I have installed both.

Comment: It seems that you didn't share all code... for example - `</tbody>` doesn't have opened tag... And why you put `<p>` in `tbody`?

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko Yeah my actual code is quite huge, so I put only the important parts.. that could've caused the problem.

Comment: Provide versions of modules - react, redux, *-router(s)

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko Added to the question. P.S. I cannot change versions of `react` or `react-router` as they break the theme I'm using.

Comment: This react is based on 0.13 or 0.14 version?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your React is `0.13.3` version, there is [an issue](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/136) for react `<0.14`.
See Dan Abramov's (redux author) answer:

> It won't work this way with Router 1.0, until React 0.14 comes out.
>
> Top-level route handler (App) is not an owner of the lower level handlers (DashboardApp) so the context does not propagate. This will be fixed in React 0.14.

It means that your `store` won't be passed from `Provider` down to `Body`...

If you can't change version of React, try to pass store as a prop to `Body` component.

Something like:

```
import { store } from '../routes.jsx';
...
return (
  <Container>
    <Body store={ store } />
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for finding out that issue, but the same problem persists event after i upgrade to react 0.14.6

Comment: Did you try set `store` prop to `Body` component?